# Change vibration frequency based on accelerometer variation - Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, android-vibration

I would like to change the smartphone vibration frequency based on how strong you are shaking the phone on Android.

I am able to use the accelerometer and vibration, but I cannot work with two components mixed. In other words, would it be possible to get the "strength" of the accelerometer and to put this "strength" in a variable as vibration input?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing? Once you have sensor readings you define a threshold. This threshold define that you are interested in the acceleration higher than the threshold
[Sensor example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html). 
  You can use this threshold(s) to call the vibrate( long [] patern , int repeat)

Comment: Thank you for replay. Imagine you Shake your hand and the frequency Of vibration change gradually base on the shaking intensity. Tris is the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems from the api of vibration that you can create certain patterns of vibrations.. sychas vubrate for n mili second pause for m mili second and so on.. i dont think you can make it vibrate sttronger or milder.

Comment: no, I agree that it is impossible to work on vibration intensity, but I would on frequency. My problem is to keep vibration sensible in order that a user can detect its reduction. Does make it sense?

Comment: I hope you could help me with this issue. Thank you very much

Comment: I dont think you can change the frequency either thats what I understood from other posts. Between I am very new to android (1 week experience)

Comment: Could anyone help me please?